# Let $f(z) = 1/z$ be defined on $\{ z \in \Bbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$. Then can we find an entire function $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $|z| > 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, inverse

> Let $f(z) = 1/z$ be defined on $\{ z \in \Bbb{C} : |z| > 1\}$. Then can we find an entire function $g$ such that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $|z| > 1$?

Now, can we plainly apply uniqueness theorem and say that such a function $g$ can not exist?

Comment: Yeah, a uniqueness approach will work.  Try using Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Define $h(z) = f(z) - g(z)$ then $h(z) \equiv 0$ for all $|z|>1$. This means that $\oint_{|z|=r}h(z)dz = 0$ for any $r>1$. But $\oint_{|z|=r}h(z)dz = \oint_{|z|=r}f(z)dz  - \oint_{|z|=r}g(z)dz = \ldots$

Comment: @AntonioVargas To apply Liouville's theorem, we need bounded function. I am not able to figure out what you are saying.

Comment: @Winther $ \oint_{|z|=r}h(z)dz = 1 $. Which is contradiction. :) By the way why not $ h(z) \equiv 0$ on $ \Bbb C $ directly by uniqueness theorem?

Comment: Well, it's $2\pi i$, but the exact value does not really matter just that its nonzero. How would you apply the uniqueness theorem (i.e. what is your open set and your point in it)? Note that $h$ is not analytic at $z=0$ since $f$ has a pole there so I don't see how the uniqueness theorem gives us $h\equiv 0$ for $|z|<1$.

Comment: @Winther Oops! :D I wanted to say that since $ f(z) = g(z) $ on $ |z| \gt 1 $, hence $ f \equiv g $ on $ \Bbb C $ because the set $ |z| \gt 1 $ also contains a limit point. That's why we can say $ f \equiv g $ or $ h \equiv 0 $ on $ \Bbb C $. Which is contradiction.(?)

Comment: It can be made to work, but needs a bit more work. Note that the uniquness theorem doesn't give you $h\equiv 0$ directly on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$, but only on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then you need to study $z=0$ to derive your contradiction.

Comment: @Winther Okay. Will see if it works or else what you and others have provided is brilliant!

Comment: No worries. btw this approach is exactly what Timbuc has answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a function $g$ existed, its integral over any closed curve would be zero by Cauchy's theorem. However,

$\oint_{|z|=2}g(z)dz$

is obviously nonzero.

Comment: Why not $ h(z) \equiv 0 $ on $ \Bbb C $ directly (By uniqueness theorem)? where $ h(z) = f(z) - g(z) $ on $ |z| \gt 1 $.

Comment: @VikrantDesai Well, you should start by getting $h(z) \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ first. After that you can extend this to the entire plane.

Comment: Okay. But, I thought $ h(z) \equiv 0 $ on $ \Bbb C $ will be contradiction which will say that such a function $ g$ does not exist.

Comment: It is a contradiction, as $h(0)=f(0)-g(0)$ cannot be properly defined.

Comment: So my approach is also right. Right?

Comment: The uniqueness theorem only gives, at first use $g(z)=1/z$ on $|z|>1$. More work is needed after that.

Comment: Alternately, Since $ f(z) = g(z) $ on $ |z| \gt 1 $, hence $ f \equiv g $ on $ \Bbb C $. which is contradiction because g is entire and f is not analytic on 0. :)

Comment: How did you get from the complement of the unit disk to the entire plane?

Comment: I got there because "If two complex functions are equal on a set and if that set contains a limit point also, then both of the complex functions are equal on entire domain."(Possible misconception of mine)

Comment: Right but that entire domain for now is just the plane minus the origin.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\;g(z)\;$ is entire (i.e. analytic in the whole complex plane) and $\;g(z)=\dfrac1z\;$ on $\;|z|>1\;$ .

Since $\;\dfrac1z\;$ is analytic on $\;0<|z|\le1\;$ as well, $\;g(z)$ continues analitically $\;\dfrac1z\;$ on the punctured unit disk.

But since for any $\;z_k\to 0\;$ have that $\;g(z_k)\to g(0)\;$ and $\;g(0)\;$ is well defined, we get that $\;\dfrac1z\;$ can be analitically continued on $\;z=0\;$ as well , which of course is absurd.

Comment: Great way. Please comment about my approach too which I've put into comments above. :)

Comment: Let me write it here again. Why not $ h(z) \equiv 0 $ on $ \Bbb C $ by uniqueness theorem directly? Where $ h(z) = f(z) - g(z) $ on $ |z| \gt 1 $.